# subtuples for a tuple

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

I wish to yield the following:

```
(('A',), ('B',), ('C',), ('D',))
(('A',), ('B',), ('C','D'))
(('A',), ('B','C'), ('D',))
(('A',), ('B','C','D'))
(('A','B'), ('C',), ('D',))
(('A','B'), ('C','D'))
(('A','B','C'), ('D',))
(('A','B','C','D'),)
```

when calling `sub_combinations(('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'))`

Here's my attempt but it doesn't work:

```
def sub_combinations(segment):
   for i in range(1, len(segment)):
      for j in sub_combinations(segment[i:]):
         yield segment[:i]+j 
      yield segment
```

but I think I'm on the right track.

Additionally, I'd like to have a second argument called limit which limits the size of the sub tuples, for example `sub_combinations(('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'), 2)` would give:

```
(('A',), ('B',), ('C',), ('D',))
(('A',), ('B',), ('C','D'))
(('A',), ('B','C'), ('D',))
(('A','B'), ('C',), ('D',))
(('A','B'), ('C','D'))
```

I'm using python 3.

Comment: Have you looked into [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html)? Also, please post the actual outputs from your current function.

Comment: What you want is not called "combinations", but "set partitions".

Comment: @interjay Renamed question accordingly

Comment: Actually I think I was wrong. Set partitions would include e.g. "{{A,C},{B,D}}, while in your example the subsets all contain consecutive elements. I'm not sure what this would be called.

Comment: @interjay: subtuples might be a better phrasing ;)

Comment: @SándorKazi this is Python's way of printing a one-elemented tuple, otherwise it would just be a string with parantheses.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Handle base case - when `segment` is empty:

```
def sub_combinations(segment, size=0):
    if segment == ():
        yield ()
        return
    stop = min(size or len(segment), len(segment))
    for i in range(1, stop + 1):
        for j in sub_combinations(segment[i:], size):
            yield (segment[:i],) + j
```

Example usage:

```
>>> for x in sub_combinations(('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')):
...     print(x)
...
(('A',), ('B',), ('C',), ('D',))
(('A',), ('B',), ('C', 'D'))
(('A',), ('B', 'C'), ('D',))
(('A',), ('B', 'C', 'D'))
(('A', 'B'), ('C',), ('D',))
(('A', 'B'), ('C', 'D'))
(('A', 'B', 'C'), ('D',))
(('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'),)
```

---

```
>>> for x in sub_combinations(('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'), 2):
...     print(x)
...
(('A',), ('B',), ('C',), ('D',))
(('A',), ('B',), ('C', 'D'))
(('A',), ('B', 'C'), ('D',))
(('A', 'B'), ('C',), ('D',))
(('A', 'B'), ('C', 'D'))
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you also can live with lists instead of tuples (or aren't afraid of converting them later), you can use this:

```
def subtuples(t):
  for i in range(1<< (len(t)-1)):
    result = [ [ t[0] ] ]
    for j in range(len(t)-1):
      if (1<<j) & i:
        result[-1].append(t[j+1])
      else:
        result.append([ t[j+1] ])
    yield result

for x in subtuples(('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')):
  print(x)
```

Comment: Actually, I like the recursive algorithm of falsetru better than mine.  But maybe under some specific restrictions mine works out better.

Comment: The typical ones concerning recursions.  Most of it stack depth, memory consumption, maybe also performance.  But as I said, I *like* yours better, it's more elegant.  I just had finished mine and now am reluctant to remove it completely.  It can be better in special circumstances.

Comment: I ran [this](http://ideone.com/9Y5l9A) in CPython 3.4b3, CPython 2.7.6. And recursion version performed better (about 2x). In PyPy your version ran a loooooot faster.

Comment: Yeah, that PyPy is a neat thing.  It's like picking up a machine gun after training knife for a while.

Comment: According to [this](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/wiki/JitFriendliness), It seems like PyPy **still** doesn't like recursive use of generator ;)